# Lightning Experience Tabs Error

Tags: lightning-experience

I have an app named "Lightning Knowledge" that is using the Console Navigation. Yet, I am still getting the following error:

> Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong:  The Lightning
>   Knowledge app doesn't have the ability to view either or both:
>   recently-visited primary tabs or subtabs.

Here's what my Lightning Knowledge App looks like:

[image: Lightning Knowledge]

I have tried deleting it and recreating it. Even tried creating a new org. 
Any thing I could be missing?

Comment: For future reference: please avoid references to trailhead and clearly describe what you're trying to do independent of trailhead.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke My apologies! I saw a trailhead tag and assumed questions related to it were acceptable. However, your edits to my question have turned the question and its answer into incomprehensible gibberish. The question was related to a specific trailhead challenge and had nothing to do with the Lightning Experience or any "Tabs error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add history utility when creating the app, step called utility bar.